# Change default template suffix in Shopify?

Tags: template, theme, shopify

I want to use one of the secondary template suffixes as my primary/default product template. Is there any way to do so in Shopify?

Currently, when I create a new product it automatically selects the stock "product" template suffix by default, and I need it to automatically select my "product.bundle" suffix by default.